# I am writing a SP in SYBASE Databse, i am getting a error of type mismatch, I tried all the method I know, still it remains in place

Tags: sql, sybase

```
INSERT INTO TBLONE (            
        broad,tt,CUR,
        STARTDATE,ENDDATE,OPERATION,
        TYPE,ENT,NAMEENT,SUB,FLAG1,FLAG2,ANALYST,STATUS,
        FILE,SUBID,COMMENTS )   
  SELECT convert(char(13),broad),
         convert(numeric(7,2),tt),
         convert(char(3),CUR),
         @CUR_DATE,
         ENDDATE,
         'first',
         convert(char(4),TYPE),
         convert(char(7),ENT),
         convert(varchar(40),NAMEENT),
         convert(char(8),SUB),
         'Y',
         'Y',
         convert(varchar(255),ANALYST),
         convert(char(5),STATUS),
         convert(numeric(7,0),FILE),
         convert(varchar(5),SBID),
         convert( varchar(255),COMMENTS)  
  from #TMP_TBLPONE where LE=convert(char(7) ,@LEE)
```

I matched all the datatypes still the error is coming

"Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'CHAR' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Please guide.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what is happening.  Why do the types need to change anyway?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data in the table `#TMP_TBLPONE`, in oder to reproduce the case, and help you fixing it.

Comment: I'd start by pulling the DDL for `TBLONE` and verify the column datatypes match the datatypes of the values in the `select`/projection list; in particular I'd want to verify the datatypes for `TBLONE.{STARTDATE,ENDDATE}` vs the datatypes for `@CUR_DATE` and `#TMP_TBLPONE.ENDDATE`

Answer (score 0):

Well you have this one right here:

```
    convert(numeric(7,0),FILE),
```

what is the data type for the "FILE" column in your table?

Comment: column  name is CFILE   numeric(7,0)  DEFAULT    0       not null,

Comment: @strike5-- then the code you posted above is wrong because that says `FILE` not `CFILE`

Answer (score 0):

I think you getting a string words for  FILE column. did it try the

```
convert(char(255),FILE),
```